# Vue.js fill data before render component

Tags: jquery, ajax, vue.js

I'm newbie in Vue.js and I'm trying to create without success a simple component that consists in a selectList and I'm trying to fill its options data simulating an Ajax request, this is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <my-select></my-select>
</div>

<template id="my-template">
  <div>
    <select v-model="team">
      <option v-for="n in teams" v-bind:value="n.id">
        {{n.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <p>Selected Team: {{team}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Vue.component("my-select", {
    template: "#my-template",

    mounted: function() {
        this.getTeams().then(function(data) {
            this.teams = data;
        });
    },

    data: function() {    
        return {
            team: 0,
            teams: []
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getTeams: function() {
            var d = $.Deferred();
            setTimeout(function() {
                var teams = [
                    {id: 1, name: "Real Madrid"},
                    {id: 2, name: "Bayern München"}
                ];

                d.resolve(teams);
            }, 2000);

            return d.promise();
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: "#app"
});
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ypk60xz/2/

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a scoping issue. Remember, `function()` creates it's own scope when declared anonymously,  so `this` refers to the function. To get around this either use an arrow function (if using `ES6`) or set a variable that points to the correct context: `var self = this`:

**ES6**

```
   mounted: function() {
     this.getTeams().then(data => {
       this.teams = data;
     });
  }
```

**ES5**

```
   mounted: function() {
     var self = this;
      this.getTeams().then(function(data) {
          self.teams = data;
      });
  }
```

Here's your updated fiddle using an arrow function: https://jsfiddle.net/mrvymzgh/

And in ES5: https://jsfiddle.net/mrvymzgh/1/